# Checking what cipher suite is used in RESTClient / HTTPBuilder

Tags: groovy

I am using RESTClient which is an extension of HTTPBuilder. Is there any way to see what cipher suite is being used for each request? Note: We can see this using SSL debug logging but turning that on means things get very verbose. I was wondering if there was another way - which would just tell me the cipher suite?

Thanks